# launching dap without opening specific file

Tags: neovim, plugin-telescope

I'm using dap+dapui+dap telescope extension.
And I am using `launch.json` configuration to run django code with dap

To launch I need to open a python file and run `Dap Continue` to make dap menu show and select configuration for `launch.json`.
Is it possible to run dap without opening a python file? How?

Comment: Whatever dap + dapui is, check with that plugins repository